# Where ConfigureServices is gone in in ASP.NET Core 5 MVC

Tags: asp.net-core-5.0

I created new ASP.NET Core 5 MVC application from a template with individual accounts, there is no `Startup` class nor `ConfigureServices` method. Where are they gone? I have just a static `Main`.

```
public class Program
{
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
            
            // Add services to the container.
            var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");
            builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
            builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

            builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
            builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

            var app = builder.Build();

            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.MapRazorPages();

            app.Run();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The templates have changed. You can configure all your services using `builder.Services` . The changes are documented in this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60-samples?view=aspnetcore-7.0)